# Java parser Adding an new Inner Class

Tags: java, javaparser

I want use the Java Parser to **add an inner class to an existing class**.

I've tried

```
ClassOrInterfaceDeclaration classOrInterfaceType= cu.addClass("MyInnerClass", Modifier.PUBLIC,Modifier.STATIC);
```

but this adds a new class to the Java class i.e. not as an inner class.

Any help would be appreciated.

I want to insert a Builder into an existing class like

public class BuilderDemo {

```
public static class Builder{

}
```

}

I would like the node hierarchy look as follows:-

[ClassOrInterface Nodes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KtTk1.png)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You specified `STATIC`. `static` and 'inner' are mutually exclusive.

Comment: Reference: [JLS #8.1.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.3).

Answer (score 0):

You should first find the AST node of the class in which you want to add the inner class. What you are doing is adding the class in `cu` which I bet is a `CompilationUnit`, i.e., the whole file. So you are adding a class directly in the file.